# Slow down the range function

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm blitting my sprites just fine but I want it to cycle through the files slower to look more like an explosion should. Currently its running through the files so fast its not uniform

```
class Hit_animation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, enemy_x, enemy_y):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    imageFiles = ["sprites/explosion{}.png".format(num) for num in range (1,5)]
    for files in imageFiles:
           self.image = pygame.image.load(files)
           self.image.convert()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = enemy_x
    self.rect.y = enemy_y
    self.dx = -1

def update(self, enemy_x, enemy_y):
    self.rect.x += self.dx
```

I would like to implement some form of delay.  All help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with a `self.counter` built into my `Explosion` class. I store all the relevant images in a list, and then I use the `update()` call to increment the counter. When the counter divided by a 'frame rate' value moves up one integer, I move the index of the displayed image. When the number would become too big, I know the sprite's use has run out, so I `kill()` it.

Something like this:

```
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        #boilerplate code, loading images, just as you did, etc... 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.counter = 0
        self.all_images = your_list_of_sprites
        self.displayed_image = all_images[0]

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        next_frame = self.counter / someMagicInteger
        if len(self.all_images) > next_frame:
            self.displayed_image = self.all_images[next_frame]
        else:
            self.kill()
```

In this example, `someMagicNumber` is basically the 'fps' of the `Explosion`, and can be whatever you like. Since dividing integers by integers should always yield an integer in `python2.7`, this will cause it to cycle through frames until it reaches a number that is out of range of the list your images are stored in. When that happens, it calls `self.kill()` since it has clearly outlived its use.

Comment: I'm a bit confused..  using your suggestion worked as long as I didn't use the self.kill()  if I keep that out and just did a standard self.rect.x += self.dx (to make the explosion happen on the enemy the sprites would show just fine but of course  the out of range error then it stopped...?

Comment: What didn't work about `self.kill()`? I'm unclear on the error. Anyway, this code strictly just sets the image of the object to the index of the explosion frame; if you have other game logic to put in, you should do that in your `update()` as well.

Comment: i figured it out... if len(self.all_images) > next_frame  Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks so much..  We can't be scared for something to break ;)